# Table Getting deleted automatically in MYSQL server 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: mysql, jpa, jboss, ejb

I am using Mysql server on Ubuntu And my web app runs on jboss 7 .Is  there any situation where mysql table get deleted automatically ? , any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a situation where a car starts automatically? Is there a situation where a post gets posted on SO automatically? Hint: insufficient information. Remove the question or supply more information.

Comment: Could you post your persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0):

That could be caused by the fact that in your persistence.xml file you have something like:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```